# Error php mysql login de usuarios

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un problema, tengo 2 formularios, uno de registro y otro de ingreso. funciona el de registro y no funciona el de login. El error es debido a que en el form de registro hay muchos input y en el de ingreso solo 2, y me saltan varios errores de las distintas variales que quedan sin definir

```
<?php
session_start();
require("funciones.php");
    $error="";

if (array_key_exists("Logout", $_GET))

{
        //Proviene de mi-oficina.php
        session_unset();
        setcookie("CodUFree","",time()-60*60);
        $_COOKIE['CodUFree']="";
    }

else if ((array_key_exists("CodUFree",$_SESSION) AND $_SESSION['CodUFree']) OR (array_key_exists("CodUFree", $_COOKIE) AND $_COOKIE['CodUFree']))

{
        header("Location: mi-oficina.php");
    }

    if (array_key_exists("submit", $_POST))

    {
        if (!$_POST['nombre'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Debes ingresar tu nombre.";
        }
        if (!$_POST['apellido'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Debes ingresar tu nombre.";
        }
        if (!$_POST['email'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Debes ingresar un email.";
        }
        if (!$_POST['password'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Debes ingresar una contraseña .";
        }
        if (!$_POST['telefono'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Debes ingresar un número de telefono.";
        }
        if (!$_POST['profesion'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Debes indicar a que te dedicas";
        }
        if (!$_POST['ciudad'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Ingresa la ciudad donde vives";
        }
        if (!$_POST['estado'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Ingresa la Provincia o Estado donde te encuentras";
        }
        if (!$_POST['zip'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Debes ingresar tu código postal";
        }
        if (!$_POST['direccion'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Debes ingresar una dirección.";
        }
        if ($error!="")
        {
            $error="<p>Hubo algun(os) error(es) en el formulario:".$error."</p>";
        }


else
        {   
            if ($_POST['registro']=='1')
                {   
                    $query="SELECT CodUFree FROM usuariosfree WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['email'])."' LIMIT 1";
                        $result = mysqli_query($enlace, $query);
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
                        {
                            $error="El email ya esta registrado.";
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            $query="INSERT INTO usuariosfree(nombre,apellido,email,password,telefono,profesion,pais,ciudad,estado,zip,direccion,direccion2) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['nombre'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['apellido'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['email'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['password'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['telefono'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['profesion'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['pais'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['ciudad'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['estado'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['zip'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['direccion'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['direccion2'])."')";
                            if (!mysqli_query($enlace,$query))
                            {
                                $error="<p>No hemos podido completar el registro, por favor intentelo más tarde</p>";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Actualizar el almacenamiento del password
                                $query="UPDATE usuariosfree SET password='".md5(md5(mysqli_insert_id($enlace)).$_POST['password'])."' WHERE CodUFree=".mysqli_insert_id($enlace)." LIMIT 1";
                                mysqli_query($enlace,$query);

                                $_SESSION['CodUFree']=mysqli_insert_id($enlace);
                                if ($_POST['permanecerIniciada']=='1')
                                {
                                    setcookie("CodUFree",mysqli_insert_id($enlace),time()+60*60*24*365);
                                }
                                header("Location: mi-oficina.php");
                            }
                        }
                }
            else
            {   

                //Comprobar inicio de sesion
                $query= "SELECT * FROM usuariosfree WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['email'])."'";
                $result=mysqli_query($enlace,$query);
                $fila=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                if (isset($fila)) 
                {
                    $passwordHaseada=md5(md5($fila['CodUFree']).$_POST['password']);
                    if ($passwordHaseada==$fila['password']) 
                    {
                        $_SESSION['CodUFree']=$fila['CodUFree'];
                        if ($_POST['permanecerIniciada']=='1')  
                        {
                            setcookie("CodUFree",$fila['CodUFree'],time()+60*60*24*365);
                        }
                        header("Location: mi-oficina.php");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $error="El email y/o contraseña no están registrado/s";
                    }
                }
                else
                    {
                        $error="El email y/o contraseña no están registrado/s";
                    }
            }
        }   
    }

?>
```

Comment: Edita tu código para que te podamos ayudar. No se entiende nada.

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que te da?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\Steller\ingresar.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined index: apellido in C:\xampp\htdocs\Steller\ingresar.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined index: telefono in C:\xampp\htdocs\Steller\ingresar.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined index: profesion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Steller\ingresar.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined index: ciudad in C:\xampp\htdocs\Steller\ingresar.php on line 42

Notice: Undefined index: estado in C:\xampp\htdocs\Steller\ingresar.php on line 46

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes el formulario que llama a  `ingresar.php`?  El mismo debe tener inputs con etiquetas `name` por cada valor que intentas buscar en el POST.